# Spring Cloud 1.0.2 and SR3 RestTemplate ignoring my ResponseErrorHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Using Spring Cloud, I am unable to eliminate thrown exceptions using a custom ResponseErrorHandler on my RestTemplate using the latest releases.  A year ago, we implemented something similar to   [How to Ignore HttpStatus Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868970/spring-boot-how-to-ignore-httpstatus-exceptions). This worked until we ported to spring boot/cloud 1.0.2 and greater.   Setting breakpoints in those handlers when timeouts or connectivity issues occur do not get triggered in debug mode when using Spring Cloud 1.0.2 or SR3.

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {
    :
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
      RestTemplate toRet = new RestTemplate(httpRequest());
      toRet.setErrorHandler(new ExceptionLessErrorHandler());
      return toRet;
    }
}
```

ExceptionLessErrorHandler.java

```
public class ExceptionLessErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {
      @Override
      public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) {
        return false;
      }
      @Override
      public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response)  throws IOException {
        logger.error("handleError called with {}", response);
        // do nothing!
      }
}
```

and finally when we call, using same restTemplate (I verified the ErrorHandler was set to ExceptionLessErrorHandler)

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
:
class GetRemoteJsonResponse implements Callable<List<JsonNode>> {
: 
  @Override
  public List<JsonNode> call() {
    :
    ResponseEntity<String> remoteUsers = restTemplate.getForEntity(URL.toString(), String.class, params);
  }
}
```

an exception is thrown triggered by `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`.  This was not the behavior prior to our port (we were using Spring 3.2.4) prior.

Update.   To be specific about the release of `spring-cloud-starter-parent`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Angel.SR3</version>
    <!--<version>1.0.2</version>-->
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

I have not tried other `spring-cloud-starter-parent` releases other than these two.

Comment: spring cloud 1.0.2 doesn't make sense and SR3 only does because only Angel has and SR3. Do you mean spring-cloud-netflix 1.0.2?

Comment: @spencergibb - I updated to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the exception is the result of a connection issue, ResponseErrorHandler will not be called as it is only used for response issues. The only way to stop connection issues from throwing an exception, that I'm aware of, is adding some kind of localhost Proxy via HttpConnectionFactory.

Comment: Yup, that was it.  I see that `RestTemplate.doExecute` uses the ResponseErrorHandler only after the `request.execute()` method.  That method ends up in a `ClientHttpRequest` implementation which throws an exception if a connect() fails.   That exception jumps right past RestTemplate's handleResponse() method where it is rethrown.  Hence this is a spring-web behavior and not a Spring Cloud thing.   Unlikely that will ever change.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I had to do for the Angel release train:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("custom")
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateCustomizer customizer) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new ExceptionLessErrorHandler());
    customizer.customize(restTemplate); //this brings in ribbon.
    return restTemplate;
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("custom")
RestTemplate rest;
```

Angel.X creates a `RestTemplate` and you were getting the auto-created one, not the one you created.

I've also created [an issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/60) to make this more user friendly and to document how to do this.

Comment: So I have a couple more questions now.  Isn't the `RestTemplateCustomizer` for customizing the `@LoadBalanced` RestTemplate?  Since I am not annotation the RestTemplate bean function with `@LoadBalanced`, should I be passing in the Customizer?  Also, since `RestTemplateCustomizer` is an interface, where am I getting that from?  I tried @Autowired on the function to no avail.

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to replicate the s-c-netflix customizer. There's a fix in Brixton to allow multiple customizers.